# Скрипт замены по шаблонам PowerShell

Tags: регулярные-выражения, powershell

Есть блок конфига вида:

```
{
  mainUrl: 'test.mysite.com',
  ver:     "1.0",
  secUrl:  '/'
  visible: true
}
```

Необходимо при помощи регулярных выражений заменить параметры во всех строках:
`mainUrl` на `'production.mysite.com'`, `ver` на `2.0`, `visible` на `false`, при этом все изменения должны сохраняться в этом же файле.

Решил следующим способом:
 (Get-Content .\config.js) -replace '[a-z]{4}.[a-z]{6}.[a-z]{3}', 'production.mysite.com' 
 `-replace '\d\.\d', '2.0'`
 -replace 'true$', 'false' | Set-Content .\app.js

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: Порядок параметров строгий? Возможно присутствие других параметров рядом?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/qnPkLF/1

Comment: Вероятно, это JSON5. Можно поискать библиотеку (парсер) для работы с этим форматом.

Comment: Интрересует как конкретно одной командой сделать замену параметра в первой строке, второй командой во второй и т.д.

Comment: Покажите свои наработки, что уже сделали.